# Decrypt Apple Business Chat auth token

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve, apple-business-chat

I'm looking at this integration document:

https://register.apple.com/resources/business-chat/BC_Sending_an_Auth_Msg.pdf

See "How to Decrypt Your Auth Token" section

I am using Bouncy Castle v1.8.3 for c#

I have a test console app:

```
namespace AppleBusinessChat45
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var publicKey = "BNY+I93aHVkXnNWKVLdrMJLXpQ1BsyHYoiv6UNi4rDUsRx3sNNhW8FNy9yUwxYprAwwfj1ZkoJ61Fs+SwjIbGPtXi52arvSbPglyBN4uAxtP3VP3LCP4JtSEjdgsgsretA==";
            var privateKey = "pX/BvdXXUdpC79mW/jWi10Z6PJb5SBY2+aqkR/qYOjqgakKsqZFKnl0kz10Ve+BP";
            var token = "BDiRKNnPiPUb5oala31nkmCaXMB0iyWy3Q93p6fN7vPxEQSUlFVsInkJzPBBqmW1FUIY1KBA3BQb3W3Qv4akZ8kblqbmvupE/EJzPKbROZFBNvxpvVOHHgO2qadmHAjHSmnxUuxrpKxopWnOgyhzUx+mBUTao0pcEgqZFw0Y/qZIJPf1KusCMlz5TAhpjsw=";

            var decodedToken = Base64.Decode(token);
            var decodedEphemeralPublicKey = decodedToken.Take(97).ToArray();
            var encodedEphemeralPublicKeyCheck = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Base64.Encode(decodedEphemeralPublicKey));

            if (encodedEphemeralPublicKeyCheck != "BDiRKNnPiPUb5oala31nkmCaXMB0iyWy3Q93p6fN7vPxEQSUlFVsInkJzPBBqmW1FUIY1KBA3BQb3W3Qv4akZ8kblqbmvupE/EJzPKbROZFBNvxpvVOHHgO2qadmHAjHSg==")
                throw new Exception("Public key check failed");

            X9ECParameters curveParams = ECNamedCurveTable.GetByName("secp384r1");
            ECPoint decodePoint = curveParams.Curve.DecodePoint(decodedEphemeralPublicKey);
            ECDomainParameters domainParams = new ECDomainParameters(curveParams.Curve, curveParams.G, curveParams.N, curveParams.H, curveParams.GetSeed());
            ECPublicKeyParameters ecPublicKeyParameters = new ECPublicKeyParameters(decodePoint, domainParams);

            var x = ecPublicKeyParameters.Q.AffineXCoord.ToBigInteger();
            var y = ecPublicKeyParameters.Q.AffineYCoord.ToBigInteger();

            if (!x.Equals(new BigInteger("8706462696031173094919866327685737145866436939551712382591956952075131891462487598200779332295613073905587629438229")))
                throw new Exception("X coord check failed");

            if (!y.Equals(new BigInteger("10173258529327482491525749925661342501140613951412040971418641469645769857676705559747557238888921287857458976966474")))
                throw new Exception("Y coord check failed");

            var privateKeyBytes = Strings.ToByteArray(privateKey);
            ECPrivateKeyParameters ecPrivateKeyParameters = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(new BigInteger(privateKeyBytes), domainParams);

            IBasicAgreement agree = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("ECDHC");
            agree.Init(ecPrivateKeyParameters);
            BigInteger sharedKey = agree.CalculateAgreement(ecPublicKeyParameters);
            var sharedKeyBytes = sharedKey.ToByteArrayUnsigned();

            // Expecting:
            // 2lvSJsBO2keUHRfvPG6C1RMUmGpuDbdgNrZ9YD7RYnvAcfgq/fjeYr1p0hWABeif

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation states "*The example private key is represented as the unsigned scalar converted to bytes.*" and has a value of:

pX/BvdXXUdpC79mW/jWi10Z6PJb5SBY2+aqkR/qYOjqgakKsqZFKnl0kz10Ve+BP

I may be reading the private key incorrectly? As the secret key I try and resolve does not match the expected value in the documentation.

There is little implementation detail online.

In terms of Bouncy Castle, how might the private key be read from a string and then used to produce the shared key?

**UPDATE**

For those looking for a complete example implementation of decrypting the apple chat auth token, see below:

```
namespace AppleBusinessChat45
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var privateKey = "pX/BvdXXUdpC79mW/jWi10Z6PJb5SBY2+aqkR/qYOjqgakKsqZFKnl0kz10Ve+BP";
            var token = "BDiRKNnPiPUb5oala31nkmCaXMB0iyWy3Q93p6fN7vPxEQSUlFVsInkJzPBBqmW1FUIY1KBA3BQb3W3Qv4akZ8kblqbmvupE/EJzPKbROZFBNvxpvVOHHgO2qadmHAjHSmnxUuxrpKxopWnOgyhzUx+mBUTao0pcEgqZFw0Y/qZIJPf1KusCMlz5TAhpjsw=";

            // #####
            // ##### Step 1
            // #####
            var decodedToken = Convert.FromBase64String(token);
            var decodedEphemeralPublicKey = decodedToken.Take(97).ToArray();
            var encodedEphemeralPublicKeyCheck = Convert.ToBase64String(decodedEphemeralPublicKey);

            if (encodedEphemeralPublicKeyCheck != "BDiRKNnPiPUb5oala31nkmCaXMB0iyWy3Q93p6fN7vPxEQSUlFVsInkJzPBBqmW1FUIY1KBA3BQb3W3Qv4akZ8kblqbmvupE/EJzPKbROZFBNvxpvVOHHgO2qadmHAjHSg==")
                throw new Exception("Public key check failed");

            X9ECParameters curveParams = ECNamedCurveTable.GetByName("secp384r1");
            ECPoint decodePoint = curveParams.Curve.DecodePoint(decodedEphemeralPublicKey);
            ECDomainParameters domainParams = new ECDomainParameters(curveParams.Curve, curveParams.G, curveParams.N, curveParams.H, curveParams.GetSeed());
            ECPublicKeyParameters ecPublicKeyParameters = new ECPublicKeyParameters(decodePoint, domainParams);

            var x = ecPublicKeyParameters.Q.AffineXCoord.ToBigInteger();
            var y = ecPublicKeyParameters.Q.AffineYCoord.ToBigInteger();

            if (!x.Equals(new BigInteger("8706462696031173094919866327685737145866436939551712382591956952075131891462487598200779332295613073905587629438229")))
                throw new Exception("X coord check failed");

            if (!y.Equals(new BigInteger("10173258529327482491525749925661342501140613951412040971418641469645769857676705559747557238888921287857458976966474")))
                throw new Exception("Y coord check failed");

            Console.WriteLine("Step 1 complete");

            // #####
            // ##### Step 2
            // #####
            var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
            var ecPrivateKeyParameters = new ECPrivateKeyParameters("ECDHC", new BigInteger(1, privateKeyBytes), domainParams);
            var privateKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(ecPrivateKeyParameters);
            var ecPrivateKey = (ECPrivateKeyParameters) PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privateKeyInfo);

            IBasicAgreement agree = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("ECDHC");
            agree.Init(ecPrivateKey);
            BigInteger sharedKey = agree.CalculateAgreement(ecPublicKeyParameters);
            var sharedKeyBytes = sharedKey.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
            var sharedKeyBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(sharedKeyBytes);

            if (sharedKeyBase64 != "2lvSJsBO2keUHRfvPG6C1RMUmGpuDbdgNrZ9YD7RYnvAcfgq/fjeYr1p0hWABeif")
                throw new Exception("Shared key check failed");

            Console.WriteLine("Step 2 complete");

            // #####
            // ##### Step 3
            // #####
            var kdf2Bytes = Kdf2(sharedKeyBytes, decodedEphemeralPublicKey);
            var kdf2Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(kdf2Bytes);

            if (kdf2Base64 != "mAzkYatDlz4SzrCyM23NhgL/+mE3eGgfUz9h1CFPhZOtXequzN3Q8w+B5GE2eU5g")
                throw new Exception("Kdf2 failed");

            Console.WriteLine("Step 3 complete");

            // #####
            // ##### Step 4
            // #####
            var decryptionKeyBytes = kdf2Bytes.Take(32).ToArray();
            var decryptionIvBytes = kdf2Bytes.Skip(32).ToArray();

            var decryptionKeyBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(decryptionKeyBytes);
            var decryptionIvBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(decryptionIvBytes);

            if (decryptionKeyBase64 != "mAzkYatDlz4SzrCyM23NhgL/+mE3eGgfUz9h1CFPhZM=")
                throw new Exception("Decryption key check failed");

            if (decryptionIvBase64 != "rV3qrszd0PMPgeRhNnlOYA==")
                throw new Exception("Decryption iv check failed");

            var encryptedDataBytes = decodedToken.Skip(97).Take(decodedToken.Length - 113).ToArray();
            var tagBytes = decodedToken.Skip(decodedToken.Length - 16).ToArray();

            var encryptedDataBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedDataBytes);
            var tagBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(tagBytes);

            if (encryptedDataBase64 != "afFS7GukrGilac6DKHNTH6YFRNqjSlwSCpkXDRj+")
                throw new Exception("Encrypted data check failed");

            if (tagBase64 != "pkgk9/Uq6wIyXPlMCGmOzA==")
                throw new Exception("Tag check failed");

            KeyParameter keyParam = ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", decryptionKeyBytes);
            ParametersWithIV parameters = new ParametersWithIV(keyParam, decryptionIvBytes);
            IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
            cipher.Init(false, parameters);
            var resultBytes = cipher.DoFinal(encryptedDataBytes.Concat(tagBytes).ToArray());
            var resultBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(resultBytes);
            var resultString = Strings.FromByteArray(resultBytes);

            if (resultString != "xXTi32iZwrQ6O8Sy6r1isKwF6Ff1Py")
                throw new Exception("Decryption failed");

            Console.WriteLine("Step 4 complete");
            Console.WriteLine(resultString);

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done... press any key to finish");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static byte[] Kdf2(byte[] sharedKeyBytes, byte[] ephemeralKeyBytes)
        {
            var gen = new Kdf2BytesGenerator(new Sha256Digest());
            gen.Init(new KdfParameters(sharedKeyBytes, ephemeralKeyBytes));

            byte[] encryptionKeyBytes = new byte[48];
            gen.GenerateBytes(encryptionKeyBytes, 0, encryptionKeyBytes.Length);
            return encryptionKeyBytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just trying your code, what is `sharedSecret`?

Comment: @phuzi Sorry, typo, it should have been the variable above. Now changed

Comment: their documentation is crazy bad: did you discover that the "Public Key" you have in your original first example was either a typo or somehow not used? I can't understand why it's even there if the auth token itself includes the public key originally passed in the authenticate request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
var privateKeyBytes = Strings.ToByteArray(privateKey);
ECPrivateKeyParameters ecPrivateKeyParameters = new ECPrivateKeyParameters(new BigInteger(privateKeyBytes), domainParams);

IBasicAgreement agree = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("ECDHC");
agree.Init(ecPrivateKeyParameters);
```

With this:

```
var privateKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey);
var ecPrivateKeyParameters = new ECPrivateKeyParameters("ECDHC", new BigInteger(1, privateKeyBytes), domainParams);
var privateKeyInfo = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(ecPrivateKeyParameters);
var ecPrivateKey = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)PrivateKeyFactory.CreateKey(privateKeyInfo);

var agree = AgreementUtilities.GetBasicAgreement("ECDHC");
agree.Init(ecPrivateKey);
```

and it should work.

Comment: Please use 'new BigInteger(1, privateKeyBytes)' to ensure the bytes are interpreted as a non-negative value.